# If my submit return false, how can I checked a radio button that was checked by user?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

here's my question :

I have 2 radio buttons that both display different tables. When you enter my page, I want my first one to be checked as default, only if submit hasnt been pressed. Then, if submit has been pressed and radio button 2 was on checked (by the user), checked radio button 2 (and not button 1) How can I achieve this?

```
<tr height="40px" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <td width="30px"><input type="radio" value="simpledoc"'; if ($_POST['demande']  == 'undefined') { echo 'checked';} else if (isset($_POST['demande']) && $_POST['demande'] == 'simpledoc') { echo 'checked'; } echo 'name="demande" id="simple" onclick="hidediv();"></td>
                    <td align="left" width="270px" onclick="hidediv();" style="border-right:1px solid #E9E9E9;"><label for="simple" class="txtdemande">Demande simple</label></td>
                    <td width="30px" style="border-left:1px solid #BFBFBF;"><input type="radio" value="co-demandeurdoc"'; if (isset($_POST['demande']) && $_POST['demande'] == 'co-demandeurdoc'){ echo 'checked'; }  echo 'name="demande" id="codemandeur12" onclick="showdiv();"></td>
                    <td align="left" onclick="showdiv();"><label for="codemandeur12" class="txtdemande">Avec co-demandeur</label></td>
                </tr>
```

(All my stuff is in a echo, so that's why you can see after value="simpledoc" the '; )

Comment: use javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you are processing the data once it is posted.  Are you processing it to the same form, and then you want the 2nd radio button to be checked if it was checked at submit time?
Then maybe you want something like:

```
if($_POST['demande'] == 'simpledoc'){
    $simpleDoc = "checked";
}elseif($_POST['demande'] == 'co-demandeurdoc'){
    $co_demand = "checked";
}else{
    $simpleDoc = "checked";
}
```

Then just echo $simpleDoc and $co_demand into the appropriate place in your html form.